# Trying to attach an opaque image into a non-opaque ImageWriter, or vice versa

Tags: android, surfaceview, image-reader

In Android, I have an ImageReader which emits images `onImageAvailable`. I'm trying to forward those images to an `ImageWriter` to preview on a `SurfaceView`. When I attempt to do so, I receive the error stated above.

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to attach an opaque image into a non-opaque ImageWriter, or vice versa`

I looked around and I haven't found anyone else mention this issue. Does anyone know what it is talking about? The error seems to be in native code.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this issue when trying to pass an `Image` from the camera into a `Surface` using `ImageWriter`. In my case, I fixed the problem by calling `SurfaceHolder.setFormat()` and passing in the same format that the camera `Image` is using.